# Unable to get my code to output only certain values

Tags: javascript

I am busy with a javascript program where I have a function that runs through values and outputs only the certain values that I specified.

```js
let printValuesOf = (jsObject, keys) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    console.log(jsObject[key]);
  }
}

let simpsonsCatchphrases = {
  lisa: 'BAAAAAART!',
  bart: 'Eat My Shorts!',
  marge: 'Mmm~mmmmm',
  homer: "d'oh!",
  maggie: "(Pacifier Suck)",
};

printValuesOf(simpsonsCatchphrases, 'lisa', 'bart', 'homer');

// Expected console output:

// BAAAAAART!
// Eat My Shorts!
// d'oh!

// Returns undefined
```

Comment: `let printValuesOf = (jsObject, ...keys) => {`

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the `printValuesOf` function to accept an `array` of `keys` instead of `multiple arguments`.

Try this:

```js
let printValuesOf = (jsObject, keys) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    console.log(jsObject[key]);
  }
}

let simpsonsCatchphrases = {
  lisa: 'BAAAAAART!',
  bart: 'Eat My Shorts!',
  marge: 'Mmm~mmmmm',
  homer: "d'oh!",
  maggie: "(Pacifier Suck)",
};

printValuesOf(simpsonsCatchphrases, ['lisa', 'bart', 'homer']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this,

```js
// Looped to print out the field value
let printValuesOf = (jsObject, keys) => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log(jsObject[key])
  })
}

// Sample data
let simpsonsCatchphrases = {
  lisa: 'BAAAAAART!',
  bart: 'Eat My Shorts!',
  marge: 'Mmm~mmmmm',
  homer: "d'oh!",
  maggie: "(Pacifier Suck)",
};

// To get it all at once
printValuesOf(simpsonsCatchphrases, ['lisa', 'bart', 'homer']);
```